# Windows 7 cannot access samba share (error 53 and network path was not found)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, samba

For some reason windows 7 cannot see my samba share after moving house...?...

When trying `net view \\192.168.0.6` it returns System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.

Below is some info which may be of some relevance

- Windows 7 is running inside of Parallels (but has worked prior without any issues)
- I can ping the server from Windows
- My Mac can access the samba share, which is wirelessly connected
- I've tried disabling IPv6 on my samba server (this did not solve the issue)
- I've changed my samba user password
- Checked the permissions of the shared folders
- I now have Virgin super hub rather than a BT home hub
- Samba version 3.5.6

Comment: I think the problem lies with windows, rather than the network. (But then again, I could be wrong...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I managed to fix it some how after Googling around, for me the fix was a combination of...

- Turning off public folder sharing
- Setting my NetBIOS to Default
- Ensuring I have the correct Workgroup
- Reviewing the firewall settings on Windows
- Following the steps in the answer of this [post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/unable-to-connect-to-servererror-code-0x80070043/82bedf39-a3ab-4ebb-8a1c-6c1c522e9a73)

Then after restarting, mapped the network drive as normal (ticked Connect using different credentials) and it connected.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to check is to make sure that the Windows machine's network adapter has "Client for Microsoft Networks" installed.

- Open up the Network Connections list: ncpa.cpl
- Right click on the adapter and select properties
- Ensure "Client for Microsoft Networks" is in the list
- If it's not in the list, click the Install button. select Client, and click Ok.

While an answer has already been found, I want to add this for the sake of completeness since I just wasted many hours figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the network interface mode from NAT to Bridged or vice-versa in Parallels?

What happens when you go Start ->Run and enter \\IP.address?

Is the Computer Browser service running on the remote server?  If not, then it won't advertise shares.

Comment: I've tried all three without any luck. Start/Run/Ip returns a dialog with Error code: 0x80070043 and "The network name cannot be found"

Comment: Copy the results of a ping to the server from the windows box please