# Can't access network drives anymore

Tags: windows, networking, nas

I have this annoying problem: I cannot access network drives / computers on my same network anymore! I have a QNAP (nas) on IP 192.168.178.5, and other PCs in the same network. The other PCs can access any network device storage, yet I cannot.

I even tried by putting simply

```
\\192.168.178.5 (nas)
```

It still doesn't work, saying "Windows cannot access the system, check for spelling errors".

It's not a permissions problem, since every other PC in the network can access the NAS with no problem. Only I have the problem and it's also a fairly recent one (1 week give or take, before that it was all working fine).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: run cmd.exe and enter there: `net view \\192.168.178.5`. What is the result?

Comment: System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.

Comment: Yet, I can ping and I can access the web interface of the nas...

Comment: Probably your SMB1 protocoll is deactivated. Assuming you use Windows Vista or later: look to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/855523/339147) and do the stuff described under **Enable Client-SMB1 on the W7:**. Any changes?

Comment: If you are using wifi, try to connect to the network via cable and try again to access the qnap.

Comment: @boboes no luck. maudam I am already on cable.

Comment: @ANon Do you try `\\192.168.178.5` or `\\192.168.178.5 (nas)`? What is the result of `net start mrxsmb10`?

Comment: "The requested service has already been started. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.". Of course I am doing \\192.168.178.5 . No luck so far :(

Comment: Any related events in the System or Application event logs?

Comment: Look this posting: [Windows 7 cannot access samba share (error 53 and network path was not found)](http://superuser.com/questions/583868/windows-7-cannot-access-samba-share-error-53-and-network-path-was-not-found).